# What can I use as parameters to specify the output behavior of `ls`?

Tags: linux, ls

What is the `ls` command that will produce the following output?

```
478661 .gconf/
478662 .gconfd/
450001 .gimp-2.4/
450006 .gksu.lock
478706 .gnome/
478664 .gnome2/
478667 .gnome2_private/
478669 .gnupg/
478681 .gstreamer-0.10/
478679 .ovfs/
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely

```
ls -i
```

The number in front of the filename is the [**inode**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) number, I guess.

Comment: For the output to be one entry per line you need to add "-1": `ls -1i`